# Bulk Insert SQL Server FROM network file

Tags: sql-server, bulkinsert

Can't seem to get this bulk insert to work. I know the SQL Server windows account has appropriate permissions to this network folder - that has been verified.

The error I get is: Msg 12704, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Bad or inaccessible location specified in external data source "(null)".

I can copy and paste the path into my windows finder and it opens the file but maybe I am using the wrong syntax in the SQL statement?

Here is the SQL statement:

```
BULK INSERT Employee_be.dbo.Table_Cur_Test
FROM '\\SERVERPATH\Data\Test\CurTest.txt' 
WITH    
(   
    FIELDTERMINATOR = ',',  
    ROWTERMINATOR = ';\n'   
) 

GO
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you running this command in SSMS using Sql Authentication? Is yes then it could be that the sql instance is using a service account that does not access that location?

Comment: I am running it in SSMS and the account I am using is SQL authenticated and not windows authentication.  Maybe that is the issue? If so how can the SQL Authenticated account gain access to that location if it is not a windows account?  I have added the Windows account the sql server uses.

Comment: Have you confirmed it's a permission issue by (temporarily) setting the folder and share permissions to *everyone* - you need to do both too.

Comment: I would consult with your IT. I don't know how your sql instance is setup. Do you know if the sql server service account is part of the network domain?

Comment: I just tried it using a windows authenticated account that has permissions to that folder and still the same error.

Comment: It's not always permissions related. Can the SQL Server instance resolve the `SERVERPATH` name via DNS or WINS? Do the network firewall rules allow SMB/CIFS access from the SQL Server to the file share server?

Comment: @Kevin - Can you RDP into the host server?